# examples of protocols using UDP initially followed by TCP

Tags: lua, network-protocols, wireshark

Hey SO,
What examples do you know - of protocols initially "handshaking" in UDP, then "conversing" in TCP.
I know there are heaps, I just can't seem to think of any right now.

Specifically, I'm trying to write a Wireshark dissector - for this kind of protocol.
So being able to peek on a similar dissector, seems like a good start.
Would love to hear if you've ever written a stateful Wireshark dissector in LUA.

Answer (score 1):

One example is SIP/Fax.
SIP/SDP setups the session for fax transmission, and then transfers fax/image via TCP/TPKT.

Answer (score 0):

There are several that use both UDP and TCP (see [Apple's list](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629), marked as `TCP/UDP`), but I don't know if they behave exactly as you've described (initial handshake with UDP). [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) are a couple examples.

I've written Wireshark dissectors in Lua, but not stateful ones.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a handshake would be in TCP being a stateful connection? A handshake seems like something that would want to be ordered, compared to UDP where there is stateless transmission?

Answer (score 0):

I've added some kind of statefulness for the HTTP protocol within my project aimed to [lookup original HTTP request for given HTTP response](https://github.com/shomeax/wireshark-http-extra).

Generally speaking, Lua has nice notion of closures which can be used as kind of static global variables for holding handshakes and whatever other references.